# Insert data from one table to another

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2019, pivot, data, unpivot

I have a table in which new entries come in every second. The table is just like this:

| value1 | data1 | Value2 | data2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Er | 2 | Er |
| 3 | Er | 4 | Er |

Now insert these value in other table as

| Value | data |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Er |
| 2 | Er |
| 3 | Er |
| 4 | Er |

And when new data insert into 1 table insert that data into second one in each execution of query but not previous one.

Comment: Which database system, version, and edition are you using?

Comment: Sql server ssms19.2

Comment: SSMS is a client tool to connect to SQL Server. What does `SELECT @@version;` give you?

Comment: Version is 15.0

Comment: Please explain more regarding your table structure and filter you use for new insert.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
    DECLARE @MyTableVar TABLE (
    Data1 SMALLINT,
    values1 VARCHAR(50),
    Data2 SMALLINT,
    values2 VARCHAR(50)
);
    
INSERT Table1 (data1,value1,data2,value2)
    OUTPUT INSERTED.Data1, INSERTED.Value1, INSERTED.Data2, INSERTED.Value2
        INTO @MyTableVar
VALUES (N'11', 'er2',12,'er3');
  

INSERT Table2 (data,value)
select data1,value1 from @MyTableVar
union all
select data2,value2 from @MyTableVar
```

This query just show the idea.It is not tested.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a FOR AFTER INSERT trigger. But instead of copying the inserted values to a second table, you maybe could replace the second table with the following view (where "table1" stands for the name of the first table), which you could materialize if needed:

```
    SELECT value1, data1
    FROM table1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT value2, data2
    FROM table1
```

The possible problem with that approach it that you would have no way to guarantee uniqueness of values in the "value" column, in case that would be needed.